# SQL Server does not exist or access denied error

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, ms-office, performancepoint

I have an application that runs fine when executed off the server. When clients try to connect, they receive the following error:

Failed to get data.
*Data provider could not be initialized
*SQL Server does not exist, or access denied

on my Office Web Components (MDAC). I am guessing there is some security or server configuration error, but I'm not able to pinpoint it. I am running SQL Server 2005.

*Note - clients can't change their security settings, company policy.

Comment: You've tagged this as sharepoint but haven't described the system configuration in the question. That might help?

For example, is the front-end application sharepoint? Is the application on the same server as SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2005, Sharepoint 2003, and PerformancePoint 2007 are all installed on the same box. This is a PerformancePoint dashboard that is deployed as a web-part on Sharepoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try this from a command prompt:

TELNET servername 1433

What happens? If you get a blank screen, then SQL Server is listening and you've got something wrong in your client settings. If you get an "Access denied" or "no response"-type answer, it's most likely either a firewall issue or SQL Server isn't listening, but in either case, it's a server issue.

Comment: could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: connect failed

what do I need to do make the connection work?

Comment: Sounds like a client firewall issue

Comment: i ran telnet on the server, not the client

Comment: If you ran TELNET on the server and still got this message, then I'll bet SQL Server isn't listening on TCP/IP. Open the "Server Configuration" on the server, check the protocol list, and make sure that TCP is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 disables network accessibility by default, you might need to enable it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: enabling Named Pipes, TCP/IP and VIA under network configuration actually prevented the server from connecting to the database

Comment: Although a good point in general, I disagree in this case.

The application works when executed from the server which suggests authentication issues to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall settings might be preventing connections from your clients. If not, it can be a DNS issue.

Comment: what kind of DNS issue am I looking for?

Comment: The standard - you can't resolve the server address. Try to ping or tracert it from a command prompt where the code trying to access SQL Server is failing. The TELNET command suggested here is useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an issue with your firewall not allowing remote connections?

Comment: client firewall cannot be modified

Comment: It's not a client firewall issue. The respondants are talking about any firewall between the application server and the database server.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working from the server but clients are having problems, I think the "access denied" part of the error is the key here and it's an authentication problem.

What sort of authentication are you using to authenticate your clients? Is the server using impersonation? If you're running clients and server in an active directory domain, the client application (Office or Internet Explorer for example) might be passing credentials to the server which the server is using to authenticate to the database.

Comment: i have enabled anonymous access in IIS

Comment: Have you disabled the other authentication methods?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server to be contactable from a network machine it requires port 1433 to be open on the server for TCP traffic. Additionally, if you have a named instance you should check the port it is listening on as it may be different to the the default and will probably need to be opened. You will also have to open up port 1434 for UDP to support the SQL Browser Service

Answer (score 0):

firewall issue. diable firewall, run instance again